# iOS UICollectionView skips data for cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When assigning data to my `UICollectionViewCell` it gets added but leaves a blank Cell between them.

When the `UICollectionView` is displayed I expect results to be:

[1] [2] [3] [4] and so on

But instead I get this:

[1] [ ] [2] [ ] [3] [ ] [4]

Code from `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

    _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 70) collectionViewLayout:layout];
    _collectionView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    _collectionView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES;
    _collectionView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [_collectionView setPagingEnabled:NO];
    [_collectionView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [_collectionView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
}
```

Code from `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
- (CustomCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]; //testing row

    return cell;
}
```

And my `CustomCell.m`:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:aRect];
    {
        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];

        [self addSubview:titleLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: self = [super initWithFrame:aRect];                                                                     
 if(self)   {
        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];

        [self addSubview:titleLabel];
    }
    return self;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow I could solve this!

I've logged the Subviews of the `CustomCell` and there is a bug I think when assigning the frame to `UILabel`.

Log for `titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame]`:

```html
App(
    "<UIView: 0x7b74cb00; frame = (0 0; 50 70); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7b74d0b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b74cbc0>>",
    "<UILabel: 0x7b74d0e0; frame = (0 0; 50 70); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7b74d1f0>>"
)

App (
    "<UIView: 0x7c954cf0; frame = (0 0; 50 70); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7c919a10>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c9f30e0>>",
    "<UILabel: 0x7c985bc0; frame = (55 0; 50 70); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7c952020>>"
)
```

As you can see the frame of the `UILabel` gets pushed right.

Log for `titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 70)]`:

```html
App (
    "<UIView: 0x7c2a1f00; frame = (0 0; 50 70); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7c2924f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c2a4970>>",
    "<UILabel: 0x7c2a3c60; frame = (0 0; 50 70); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7c292520>>"
)

App (
    "<UIView: 0x7c2a3f30; frame = (0 0; 50 70); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7c2a5ce0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c2a3ff0>>",
    "<UILabel: 0x7c2a5d10; frame = (0 0; 50 70); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7c2a5e20>>"
)
```

Now the frame of the `UILabel` is exactly the same as the `UICollectionViewCell` respectively as the `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to implement one of these (if not, all) methods:

```
-(CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
-(CGFloat) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section;
-(CGFloat) collectionView:(UICollectionView *) collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
```

The **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** is responsible with the sizes and the spacing between cells in a UICollectionView. Find out more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/).

Nevertheless, if you want to fully solve and find out which is the main problem, you should debug your views by pressing the 7th button on the Xcode's bottom bar(I have the 7.2 version). Here is a snapshot:

[image: Snapshot]

And this is how it should look the debugging:

[image: Debugging]

Comment: I already had these functions implemented but still skips the cells. The number of cells is correct but the values inside the UIView in the cell is not correct.